# Is setting lambda equal to zero the same thing as not applying regularization at all?

Tags: machine-learning, generalized-linear-model, regularization, overfitting, ridge-regression

If I set the regularization parameter to 0, does it essentially mean I'm not applying regularization (I've boxed the regularization bits in red)?

Also, what is this type of regularization called?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. When $\lambda=0$, no regularization is applied. Zero multiplied by any number is zero.
2. Penalizing squared coefficients is sometimes called [ridge-regression](/questions/tagged/ridge-regression), or L2 regularization. Other kinds of regularization include the LASSO or L1 regularization, which penalizes the absolute value of the coefficients. Elastic net regression is a compromise between the two, which includes both LASSO and includes both ridge regressions as special cases.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! Ahh, so by applying this type of regularization to a linear regression problem, can one say it's a ridge regression problem? Thanks for explaining a bit of the other types!

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The regularization term vanishes when $\lambda = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly! You can think of the cost function as having two parts:

- A "cost" associated with the difference between your model and the data, plus
- A "cost" for having two many non-zero coefficients.

The $\lambda$ term sets the weight on the second part of the cost function. If it's zero, then that entire term goes to zero  $\forall x, 0x=0$) and it is as if regularization were never applied.